# Asset.images slow? How do I execute functions so they don't freeze the browser?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I recently downloaded a nice mootools plugin to provide a rating system for search results on my site: [MooStarRating](http://mootools.net/forge/p/moostarrating).

It works quite well, but it is very slow to initialize. Here are the execution times I have logged (for pulling back 50 search results).

```
======== starrating ========
init:     0.06ms   50
img:      5.40ms   50
str:      0.54ms   50
each:     3.04ms   50
inject:   0.86ms   50
end:      1.52ms   50
subtotal: 11.42ms  50
-----------------
total:    571.00ms
```

Here is the `initialize` function these logs refer to (just for reference):

```
initialize: function (options) {

    lstart("starrating");

    // Setup options
    this.setOptions(options);

    // Fix image folder
    if ((this.options.imageFolder.length != 0) && (this.options.imageFolder.substr(-1) != "/"))
        this.options.imageFolder += "/";

    // Hover image as full if none specified
    if (this.options.imageHover == null) this.options.imageHover = this.options.imageFull;

    lrec("init");

    // Preload images
    try {
        Asset.images([
        this.options.imageEmpty,
        this.options.imageFull,
        this.options.imageHover
    ]);
    } catch (e) { };

    lrec("img");

    // Build radio selector
    var formQuery = this.options.form;
    this.options.form = $(formQuery);
    if (!this.options.form) this.options.form = $$('form[name=' + formQuery + "]")[0];
    if (this.options.form) {
        var uniqueId = 'star_' + String.uniqueID();
        this.options.form.addClass(uniqueId);
        this.options.selector += 'form.' + uniqueId + ' ';
    }
    this.options.selector += 'input[type=radio][name=' + this.options.radios + "]";
    // Loop elements
    var i = 0;
    var me = this;
    var lastElement = null;
    var count = $$(this.options.selector).length;
    var width = this.options.width.toInt();
    var widthOdd = width;
    var height = this.options.height.toInt();
    if (this.options.half) {
        width = (width / 2).toInt();
        widthOdd = widthOdd - width;
    }

    lrec("str");

    $$(this.options.selector).each(function (item) {

        // Add item to radio list
        this.radios[i] = item;
        if (item.get('checked')) this.currentIndex = i;

        // If disabled, whole star rating control is disabled
        if (item.get('disabled')) this.options.disabled = true;

        // Hide and replace
        item.setStyle('display', 'none');
        this.stars[i] = new Element('a').addClass(this.options.linksClass);
        this.stars[i].store('ratingIndex', i);
        this.stars[i].setStyles({
            'background-image': 'url("' + this.options.imageEmpty + '")',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'width': ((this.options.half && (i % 2)) ? widthOdd : width),
            'height': height
        });
        if (this.options.half)
            this.stars[i].setStyle('background-position', ((i % 2) ? '-' + width + 'px 0' : '0 0'));
        this.stars[i].addEvents({
            'mouseenter': function () { me.starEnter(this.retrieve('ratingIndex')); },
            'mouseleave': function () { me.starLeave(); }
        });

        // Tip
        if (this.options.tip) {
            var title = this.options.tip;
            title = title.replace('[VALUE]', item.get('value'));
            title = title.replace('[COUNT]', count);
            if (this.options.tipTarget) this.stars[i].store('ratingTip', title);
            else this.stars[i].setProperty('title', title);
        }

        // Click event
        var that = this;
        this.stars[i].addEvent('click', function () {
            if (!that.options.disabled) {
                me.setCurrentIndex(this.retrieve('ratingIndex'));
                me.fireEvent('click', me.getValue());
            }
        });

        // Go on
        lastElement = item;
        i++;

    }, this);

    lrec("each");

    // Inject items
    $$(this.stars).each(function (star, index) {
        star.inject(lastElement, 'after');
        lastElement = star;
    }, this);

    lrec("inject");

    // Enable / disable
    if (this.options.disabled) this.disable(); else this.enable();

    // Fill stars
    this.fillStars();

    lrec("end");

    return this;
},
```

So, the slowest part of the function is this:

```
    // Preload images
    try {
        Asset.images([
        this.options.imageEmpty,
        this.options.imageFull,
        this.options.imageHover
    ]);
    } catch (e) { };
```

Which is strange. What does `Asset.images` do? Does the script block until these images have been loaded by the browser? Is there a way to preload images that runs faster?

How can I make the scripts on my page execute faster? It is a big problem for them to take 800ms to execute, but 200ms is still quite bad. At the moment, my search results all pop into existence at once. Is it possible to make it so that individual search results are created separately, so that they don't block the browser while being created? Similarly, is it possible to do this for the individual components of the search results, such as the MooStarRating plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. Asset.images is non-blocking as each of these gets loaded separately and a singular event is being dispatched when all done.

the speed for loading will be dependent on the browser but it be will multi-threaded to whatever capability it has for parallel downloading from the same host.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Utilities/Assets.js#L115-129

immediately, it returns an Element collection with the PROMISE of elements that may still be downloading. that's fine - you can use it to inject els, attach events, classes etc - you just cannot read image properties yet like width, height.

each individual image has it's own `onload` that fires an `onProgress` and when all done, an `onComplete` for the lot - i would advise you to enable that, remove the try/catch block and see which image is creating a delay. you certainly don't need to wait for anything from Asset.images to come back.

you also seem to be using it as a 'prime the cache' method, more than anything - as you are NOT really saving a reference into the class instance. your 'each' iteration can probably be optimised so it uses half the time if objects and functions are cached and so are references. probably more if you can use event delegation.

To answer your questions about not freezing the browser due to the single-threaded nature of javascript, you defer the code via setTimeout (or Function.delay in mootools) with a timer set to 0 or a 10ms due to browser interpretations. You also write the function to to exec a callback when done, in which you can pass the function result, if any (think ajax!).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had a look at the `each` loop, to optimize it - `setStyles` is suprisingly slow! I saved lots of time by condensing 3 calls of that function into 1.

Comment: it is slow-er because it overloads each property to `element.setStyle` - you are better off working with a single CSS class being added and then any pos/height etc to change style itself. the events you add can also be saved into the class and not created in new functions on every loop etc--if you don't delegate them beforehand. much to be gained :)